# ActionScript3 ajax, cant send a simple json

Tags: ajax, json, actionscript-3

I dont know AS3 at all,

I'm trying to send to a server the following json:

```
{ userDTO : 
            {  
                name : "John"
            }
}
```

(I need this specific structure)

here is my code:

```
var loader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://test.com"); 
var hdr:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.requestHeaders.push(hdr);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

request.data = {"userDTO " : {name : "John"}};  

//  Handlers  
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, on_complete);  
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.load(request);
```

This doesnt work (the server has issues with receiving the json)

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure to clearly understand your question.

Perhaps you should try to send the json in a non-AMF format.

Like :

```
var myData : Object = {"userDTO " : {name : "John"}};
request.data = JSON.encode(myData);
```

Does it help you ?